# how get power button click event

Tags: android

I am trying capture power click in my android app, I was looking for any solution and I just find one with good results, It is when I detect screenOn/screenOff like this:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private boolean screenOff;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {
            screenOff = true;
        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
            screenOff = false;
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(context, PowerButtonService.class);
        i.putExtra("screen_state", screenOff);
        context.startService(i);
    }
}
```

The problem in this method is that in my app I am looking for do it with screen Off, then it is not util for me.

I tryed this code also in my MainActivity but this doesn't work, debuging it, this the execution go inside when I push vol up or down but not when I push power key:

```
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        Log.i("Main", "Dispath event power");
        Intent closeDialog = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS);
        sendBroadcast(closeDialog);
        Log.d("DISPATCH", "boton pulsado");
        return true;
    }
    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

I have the same problem in this one:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POWER) {
        Log.w("Test", "Power button down detected");
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Could someone help me? thanks

Edit:  I want to catch short key press

Sorry for my english

Comment: Wouldn't detecting onPaused be enough? Is there a specific reason you want to detect the power button press?

Comment: I tryed to use onPause and onResume events to simulate power button, but i can't detect if onPause was activate for timeout screen or power button click then I think that is best solution get screenOn/screenOff but I need capture clip power key.

In my app I have may events in diferents keys (vol up, vol down, home) and the last event is for power button.